# Show Checkboxes on select box using jquery in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have two tables in database: `city` and `local_area`

```
city :
id     name  
1      FSD  
2      LHr  

Local_area :
id     city_id     name  
1      1           Kohnoor  
2      1           samnabad  
3      2           joharabad  
4      2           amanabad  

<select>
  <option value="1">Fsd</option>
  <option value="2">LHR</option>
</select>
```

I have a select box that allows to me to choose the city to display.  When I select a city it should show a new HTML element showing all `local_area` for the given city.

I Have to do this using jQuery, after selection I want to store my record in database table.

Comment: Can you try a bit harder to explain what it is you've got, your formatting is all over the show and I am none the wiser to your problem after reading it.

Comment: Have you try something ?

Comment: i want onchnage function pass value to php file and show result in checkboxes  .

Comment: do you have some code already? you could use AJAX to call php script onchange to generate checkboxes and display in predefined `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`jQuery AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to "ask" a server for list of areas corresponding to the city. Or, may be, it would be better for you to load full list of all areas with page. For example:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="city" name="city">
  <option value="0">- Select -</option>
  <option value="1">Fsd</option>
  <option value="2">LHR</option>
</select>
<div id="area" style="display:none">
</div>
<script language="JavaScript">
var areas = {
 '1' : { '1' : 'Kohnoor' },
 '2' : { '1' : 'amanabad' }
}
$(function (){
    var areaSelect = $('#area');
    var citySelect = $('#city').change(function (){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if( value && typeof areas[value] != 'undefined' ){
            areaSelect.empty().show();
            for( var i in areas[value] ){
                areaSelect.append('<input type="checkbox" name="area[]" value="'+i+'" />'+areas[value][i]+'<br />');
            }
        }else{
            areaSelect.empty().hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: the code that is send i run it on my localhostits not working whats the missing in this code?

Comment: Typed "<script>" instead of "</script>". Fixed. And dont forget about jQuery.

Comment: working some better now.more edit in this that localarea should be display in checkboxes

Comment: I cannot do all the work for you. You have to modify the script to fit your needs. If need checkboxes, that replace `<select>` with `<div>` and `<option>...</option>` with `<input type="checkbox" />` and so on.

Comment: yup i trying but its not run i will aprreciated if you done last time for it to me

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="ddCity">
 <option value="-1"></option>
 <option value="1">FSD</option>
 <option value="2">LHr</option>
</select>
<div id="local_area_Grid"></div>

<script>
     $(function(){
        $("#ddCity").change(function(){
           if($(this).val() != -1){
           $.ajax({
                url: "Server_address",
                data:{cityId = $(this).val()},
                success: function(data){
                      var _table = $("<table></table>");
                      for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
                          $("<tr></tr>").append($("<td></td>").html("<label><input type='checkbox' value='data[i]' name='local_area'/>" + data[i] + "</label>")).appendTo(_table);
                      }
                      $("#local_area_Grid").html("").append(_table);
                }
           });
           }
        });
     })
</script>
```

You should return an array from service

Comment: :in code senerio that you send i want if i select lahore than in result i want retrive localareas of LHR

Comment: you have to filter the localareas in server-side. i send selected city to server by cityId parameter. You should get this parameter and filter the areas and returned them in array